# Average Days to Sale Excluding Weekends

Tags: mysql

I am working on a query to show me the average time it takes each of my clients to pay their invoice. However, I do not want to count weekend days in the average. Below is what I am currently working on and not really sure what it's outputting.

Is there a way to count average days to payment excluding weekend days?

```
SELECT CUSTOMER NAME,
AVG(TIMEDIFF(INVOICE_DT, PAYMENT_DT))
FROM PAYMENT_TABLE
WHERE 5 * (TIMEDIFF('2015-04-24 23:59:59', '2015-02-24 00:00:00') DIV 7) + MID('0123444401233334012222340111123400012345001234550', 7 * WEEKDAY('2015-02-24') + WEEKDAY('2015-04-24') + 1, 1)
GROUP BY CUSTOMER NAME;
```

Comment: this may help you http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek

Comment: Isn't it just a different string: 0123455501234445012333450122234501101234000123450?

Comment: The query processes, but I'm not sure what the output is either. One value for example is 256312.3076923077.